# Case doesn't work when examining tail output

Tags: bash, case, glob, tail, pihole

I can't find the reasons why my `case` statement doesn't work when looking tail output.

```
tail -F -n1 /var/log/pihole.log |
while read input; do
 echo "$input" | hexdump -C            # just to physically compare the output
 case $input in
   cached|blacklisted|blocked)
     echo "We have a match!";;
   *)
     echo "No match!"
 esac
done
```

This always returns `No match!`, even if the strings are in the `$input`.

```
:~ $ ./pihole_test.sh
00000000  4a 61 6e 20 31 20 31 31  3a 35 35 3a 35 38 20 64  |Jan 1 11:55:58 d|
00000010  6e 73 6d 61 73 71 5b 36  39 36 5d 3a 20 65 78 61  |nsmasq[696]: exa|
00000020  63 74 6c 79 20 62 6c 61  63 6b 6c 69 73 74 65 64  |ctly blacklisted|
00000030  20 70 6c 61 79 2e 67 6f  6f 67 6c 65 2e 63 6f 6d  | play.google.com|
00000040  20 69 73 20 30 2e 30 2e  30 2e 30 0a              | is 0.0.0.0.|
0000004c
No match!
```

Comment: Edit the question to include example input so we know what we are working with

Comment: Replace `echo $input` with `echo "$input" | hexdump -C` and add output to your question (no comment here).

Comment: Why do you need the loop though? Simply `tail -F -n1 /var/log/pihole.log | grep -E 'cached|blacklisted|blocked'` will extract any matching lines. Maybe `grep -E 'cached|blacklisted|blocked|$'` --color=yes` if you want to see all lines but highlight the matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
cached|blacklisted|blocked)
```

with

```
*cached*|*blacklisted*|*blocked*)
```

to match substrings.